# printf call in subroutine leads to program crash

Tags: c, assembly, arm, printf

I am using the IAR Embedded Workbench to write a C program to run on the Allwinner V831 SoC with an ARMv7 core. The SoC is on the MAIX-II Dock and I boot the system via an SD-Card.

I have a problem with the `printf` function. In most cases it works just fine but if I call `printf` in a subroutine which is called from `main` and the `printf` call is the last thing that happens in the function then the program completely crashes. Also interestingly this only happens if the subroutine is written in a separate file than the `main` function.
I wrote two test functions:

```
void printf_no_fail() {
  printf("no fail 1\n");
  printf("no fail 2\n");
  printf("no fail 3\n");
  volatile int x = 3;
  volatile int y = x + 7;
}

void printf_fail() {
  printf("fail 1\n");
  printf("fail 2\n");
  printf("fail 3\n");
}
```

I call both these functions in `main`. The first one runs perfectly fine and prints all three messages. The second one breaks the program: Only the first two messages are printed and then the program crashes which I know because other code that comes in the `main` function is not executed.

I took a look at the assembler instructions in the list-file and there I did notice a difference.

```
      1          #include <stdio.h>
      2          

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
      3          void printf_no_fail() {
   \                     printf_no_fail:
   \        0x0   0xE92D'5000        PUSH     {R12,LR}
      4            printf("no fail 1\n");
   \        0x4   0x....'....        ADR      R0,?_0
   \        0x8   0x....'....        BL       printf
      5            printf("no fail 2\n");
   \        0xC   0x....'....        ADR      R0,?_1
   \       0x10   0x....'....        BL       printf
      6            printf("no fail 3\n");
   \       0x14   0x....'....        ADR      R0,?_2
   \       0x18   0x....'....        BL       printf
      7            volatile int x = 3;
   \       0x1C   0xE3A0'0003        MOV      R0,#+3
   \       0x20   0xE58D'0000        STR      R0,[SP, #+0]
      8            volatile int y = x + 7;
   \       0x24   0xE59D'3000        LDR      R3,[SP, #+0]
   \       0x28   0xE283'C007        ADD      R12,R3,#+7
   \       0x2C   0xE58D'C000        STR      R12,[SP, #+0]
      9          }
   \       0x30   0xE8BD'8001        POP      {R0,PC}
     10          

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
     11          void printf_fail() {
   \                     printf_fail:
   \        0x0   0xE92D'5000        PUSH     {R12,LR}
     12            printf("fail 1\n");
   \        0x4   0x....'....        ADR      R0,?_3
   \        0x8   0x....'....        BL       printf
     13            printf("fail 2\n");
   \        0xC   0x....'....        ADR      R0,?_4
   \       0x10   0x....'....        BL       printf
     14            printf("fail 3\n");
   \       0x14   0xE8BD'4002        POP      {R1,LR}
   \       0x18   0x....'....        ADR      R0,?_5
   \       0x1C   0x....'....        B        printf
     15          }

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
   \                     ?_0:
   \        0x0   0x6E 0x6F          DC8 "no fail 1\012"

   \              0x20 0x66    

   \              0x61 0x69    

   \              0x6C 0x20    

   \              0x31 0x0A    

   \              0x00
   \        0xB                      DS8 1

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
   \                     ?_1:
   \        0x0   0x6E 0x6F          DC8 "no fail 2\012"

   \              0x20 0x66    

   \              0x61 0x69    

   \              0x6C 0x20    

   \              0x32 0x0A    

   \              0x00
   \        0xB                      DS8 1

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
   \                     ?_2:
   \        0x0   0x6E 0x6F          DC8 "no fail 3\012"

   \              0x20 0x66    

   \              0x61 0x69    

   \              0x6C 0x20    

   \              0x33 0x0A    

   \              0x00
   \        0xB                      DS8 1

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
   \                     ?_3:
   \        0x0   0x66 0x61          DC8 "fail 1\012"

   \              0x69 0x6C    

   \              0x20 0x31    

   \              0x0A 0x00

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
   \                     ?_4:
   \        0x0   0x66 0x61          DC8 "fail 2\012"

   \              0x69 0x6C    

   \              0x20 0x32    

   \              0x0A 0x00

   \                                 In section .text, align 4, keep-with-next
   \                     ?_5:
   \        0x0   0x66 0x61          DC8 "fail 3\012"

   \              0x69 0x6C    

   \              0x20 0x33    

   \              0x0A 0x00
```

In the `printf_no_fail` function all the `printf` calls are done with a Branch with Link instruction and in the `printf_fail` the first two are done the same way but the last call is done with a simple Branch and the link register is popped of the stack before the call which is only possible because the function ends right after the call.

I assume it is a problem with the linker since it seems to be related to the link register somehow and also only happens when the functions are written in a different file than `main` but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Anyone got any ideas what the problem might be?

Edit:

I compile the program and generate a raw binary as additional output. I copy the binary to the boot area of the SD card and adjust the instruction jumped to to be the first instruction of `main`.

At the beginning I turn on the onboard LED to see if the program is running. I have an infinite loop to see if the LED toggles which is how I know that after the `printf_fail` call the program doesn't continue executing as it should. The loop counting to 10 million is to delay the output because I need time to connect the board to my serial terminal. I overwrite the `__write` function and then use the `printf` from the C library.

main.c

```
#define PH_CONF1_REG       0x0300B100

void uart0_init(void);
void printf_no_fail(void);
void printf_fail(void);

int main(void) {
  uart0_init();
  
  *((unsigned int*)PH_CONF1_REG) &= 0xF8FFFFFF;
  *((unsigned int*)PH_CONF1_REG) |= 0x01000000;         // turn on led
  
  for(;;) {     // inifite loop to show if led is toggling
    for (volatile int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++);        // delay so I can see the output
        
      printf_no_fail();
      printf_fail();
      
      *((unsigned int*)PH_CONF1_REG) ^= 0x06000000;     // toggle led
  }
  return 0;
}
```

uart.c

```
#define UART0_BASE      0x05000000

#define UART0_RBR (UART0_BASE + 0x0)    /* receive buffer register */
#define UART0_THR (UART0_BASE + 0x0)    /* transmit holding register */

#define UART0_DLL (UART0_BASE + 0x0)    /* divisor latch low register */
#define UART0_DLH (UART0_BASE + 0x4)    /* divisor latch high register */

#define UART0_LCR (UART0_BASE + 0xc)    /* line control register */
#define UART0_LSR (UART0_BASE + 0x14)   /* line status register */

#define UART0_FCR (UART0_BASE + 0x8)    /* fifo control register */

#define GPIO_PH_CFG1    0x0300B100
#define GPIO_PH_PULL0   0x0300B118
#define UART_BGR        0x0300190C      /* uart bus gating reset register */

void uart0_init(void) {
  /* set GPIO PH9 to UART0_TX, PH10 to UART0_RX */
  *((unsigned int*)GPIO_PH_CFG1) &= 0xFFFFF00F;
  *((unsigned int*)GPIO_PH_CFG1) |= 0x00000550;
  *((unsigned int*)GPIO_PH_PULL0) |= 0x00100000;
  
  /* init UART clock */
  *((unsigned int*)UART_BGR) |= 0x00010001;

  /* select dll dlh */
  *((unsigned int*)UART0_LCR) = 0x80;
  /* set baudrate to 1.5M Baud*/
  *((unsigned int*)UART0_DLH) = 0x0;
  *((unsigned int*)UART0_DLL) = 0x1;
  /* set line control : no parity, one stop bit, 8 bit data packets*/
  *((unsigned int*)UART0_LCR) = 0x3;
  /* enable FIFOs */
  *((unsigned int*)UART0_FCR) = 0x1;
}

unsigned int __write(int handle, const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned int size) {
  unsigned int n = 0;
  if (handle == -1) return 0;
  for ( ; size > 0; size--) {
    while (!(*((unsigned int*)UART0_LSR) & (1 << 6)));
    if(*buffer == '\n') {
      *((unsigned int*)UART0_THR) = '\r';
      while (!(*((unsigned int*)UART0_LSR) & (1 << 6)));
    }
    *((unsigned int*)UART0_THR) = *buffer++;
    n++;
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Please post [mcve] including `main`

Comment: Q: I assume you're using the standard C library printf.  So there's NO REASON either function should crash ... from what you're showing us.  There's something important you're NOT showing us :(  Like Eugene Sh. said - we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Make two identical functions (except for their name) consisting of 3 printf only. One function in the same file as `main` and the other in another file. In `main` first call the local function then call the external function. Check that it still crash. Compare the asm of the two functions.

Comment: @Layla - The _linker_ and the _link register_ have nothing to do with each other, you know?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.   Other commenters have mentioned that we need some more information.  I have an additional question. Please define "crash".  You are running an embedded program on and ARM processor.  Can you break into the debugger?  Has it hit a hard fault?  Stuck in infinite loop?  Try to take a look at what is going on in the processor; it might give a useful hint.

Comment: The link register gets its value at runtime, from the absolute address of where the caller was executing.  (PC).  Linker relocations affect the destination that gets filled in for the `bl` target, but the linker can't break `bl foo` / `bx lr` call/ret other than by making `bl foo` go to the wrong place.

Comment: @Layla - I think you'll have to check whether a correct [veneer](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0042/latest#use-of-ip-by-the-linker) is inserted and addressed by the linker in the `B        printf` instruction.

Comment: @Armali: I think you hit the nail on the head!  References: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893770/, https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1406301797482.htm

Comment: I don't see a solution to the problem at hand in the other question's answers.

Comment: @Armali - I have checked the binary output and the veneer is ok, the address loaded into the `pc` register corresponds with the address of the `printf` function that I get from the map file

Comment: Interesting. How can you tell that it crashes and not hangs somewhere in an endless loop? Can you interrupt the processor?

Comment: No, sadly I don't know any way to access the processor. I don't know what the processor does but I can tell the program doesn't continue running as planned because of the infinite loop in `main` that toggles the LED on the carrier board. Without the call to `printf_fail` the LED toggles, with the call inlcuded it doesn't.

Comment: It will be _very_ hard to find the error without any software or hardware debugging tools. My probably last ideas are 1. put LED toggles also in the loop in the `__write` function to see if it gets in and out of there; 2. see if you can get an emulator where the binary can be executed and inspected; 3. install an operating system on the device.